# How to make Custom Loop not crop featured images?

Tags: images

When using Custom Loop to display a lot of posts on a page, you use Featured Image to display the images on that page. However, cropping occurs if the images are higher than 208 pixels, and I want my images to display at their original size ( about 210x270 ). 
How do I prevent the cropping of the images.

Answer (score 1):

You can use: [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) function

```
 <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?>
```

In the size paramenters you can pass a two dimensional array of height, and width, or use 'full' to get the full image.

Comment: I second the use of "full" in the theme file.